# How to use ape server with asp.net?

Tags: .net, ape

I have a .NET appliation running in my windows machine. I need it to use APE for publishing data to clients in real time. I have a APE server running in a seperate linux machine. My question is , how can i access the remote APE server from my .NET applications's Javascript code

Any tutorial will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've not implemented it yet, but as far as I know APE is just a (special) stand-alone web server.

To "push" data to your clients, just do a HTTP POST to APE's server (say using WebClient in C#), specifying the payload and channel/pipe to send down to, and have your clients connect to the APE server.